# Webpack bundling custom Utilities separately from App code

Tags: node.js, webpack, bundle

I would like to bundle up my TypeScript ReactJs project using webpack. As my project is rather large, I want to bundle the utils separately from the main App code, so I can keep them separate.

I have the following folder structure;

```
Scripts
    - App
        - Components
            - ComponentOne.tsx
        - App.tsx
    - Utilities
        - Interfaces
            - IHelperInterface.ts
        - Interfaces.ts
```

`ComponentOne` imports `IHelperInterface` with a an import statement `import { IHelperInterface } from '../../Utilities/Interfaces/IHelperInterface';`

Along with my custom Utils, I am also using npm for various packages.

So my current webpack config looks like this;

```
var webpack = require('webpack'),
    pkg = require('./package.json');

module.exports = {
    entry: {
        app: './scripts/app/app',
        vendor: Object.keys(pkg.dependencies)
    },

    output: {
        filename: '[name].bundle.js',
        path: __dirname + '/wwwroot/js/app'
    },

    plugins: [
        new webpack.optimize.CommonsChunkPlugin({ name: 'vendor', filename: 'vendor.bundle.js' })
    ],

    // Enable sourcemaps for debugging webpack's output.
    devtool: 'source-map',

    resolve: {
        // Add '.ts' and '.tsx' as resolvable extensions.
        extensions: ['.ts', '.tsx', '.js', '.json']
    },

    module: {
        rules: [
            // All files with a '.ts' or '.tsx' extension will be handled by 'awesome-typescript-loader'.
            { test: /\.tsx?$/, loader: 'awesome-typescript-loader' },

            // All output '.js' files will have any sourcemaps re-processed by 'source-map-loader'.
            { enforce: 'pre', test: /\.js$/, loader: 'source-map-loader' }
        ]
    }
};
```

My vendor files (npm packages) are being bundled together, and currently the rest is then bundled into 1 file. How can I modify the config to bundle my Utils?

I tried adding a 2nd entry point;

```
entry: {
    app: './scripts/app/app',
    utils: './scripts/interfaces',
    vendor: Object.keys(pkg.dependencies)
},
```

In the hope that this would work, however it created `utils.bundle.js` file, but the `app.bundle.js` file still had all the code in it.

Comment: Have you tried to add other `CommonsChunkPlugin` with `name: "utils"`?
I think it can help.

Comment: Would that just be adding `new webpack.optimize.CommonsChunkPlugin({ name: 'utils', filename: 'utls.bundle.js' })`?

Comment: Yes please try that, and let me know if it works

Comment: Ok, I tried adding a 2nd `CommonsChunkPlugin` and got an error, so changed my code to be `new webpack.optimize.CommonsChunkPlugin({ names: ['vendor', 'utils'], minChunks: Infinity })`. It seems to generate the Utils file now, but has a load of react stuff in it also? I would have thought it would just have been the Utils code and let the Vendor file take care of the React bundling?